# Marketing Cloud Automation Studio Folders

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I'm looking at automation studio, and there is an entire column dedicated to folders. But I cannot find how to create a new folder. Where is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to expand the folder option similar to the attached images.  Then you will right click the "my automations" folder and you'll see the option to to add new folders.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks that does it. I had to specifically right click on "my automations" (not "browse all automations")